# function doesn't change the value and animation disappears

Tags: javascript, html, animation, button

I'm using script to animate the pendulum found on the Internet. Now i want to add buttons to change any of the parameters of pendulum which is declared global. I'm trying global function by onclick in HTML but after click the animation disapeared...

```js
var pendulum = {mass: 100, length:500, theta: (Math.PI/2) - 0.05, omega: 0, alpha:0, J:0};

/* My changes... */
function changeBig(){
    pendulum = {mass: 100, length:100, theta: (Math.PI/2) - 0.05, omega: 10, alpha:0, J:0};
}

function changeSmall(){
    pendulum = {mass: 100, length:100, theta: (Math.PI/2) - 0.05, omega: 1, alpha:0, J:0}; 
}
/* My changes end */
```

```css
canvas {
    display:block;
    margin:0px auto;
    height:600px;
    width:400px;
    border:none;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="600" width="400"></canvas>
<button onClick="changeSmall()">Small</button>
<button onclick="changeBig()">Huge </button>
```

So what should I change to make this buttons work, I mean change omega here (how far pendulum will be swinging?

Comment: We can't answer without knowing your pendulum code that you found. Wild guess: you probably should change the `omega` property of `pendulum` and not overwrite it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bkanber/uvYw5/light/ this is it.
I don't want to chage the property, I want to make pendulum moe interactive with "user", me. At the goal I planned to make 4 buttons with diffrent omega each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just overwrite the `pendulum` object. It is used during animation to change values.

The easy fix is to change the omega values

```
function changeBig(){
    pendulum.omega = 10;
}

function changeSmall(){
    pendulum.omega = 1;
}
```

Everything more involved would require a substantial refactoring of the code.

Comment: This one works. Thank you for helping :)